# Serializing form to json correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, serialization

How would i serialize a form like this:

```
<form id="SomeForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="testId" value="123" />

    <input type="radio" name="question-1" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="question-1" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="question-1" value="3" />

    <input type="radio" name="question-2" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="question-2" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="question-2" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" name="question-2" value="4" />
</form>
```

To a JSON structure somthing like this:

```
{ 
"testid" : 123,
"questions" : [   
    { "question" : [ {
        "id" : 1,
        "answer" : 2
    }]},
    { "question" : [ {
        "id" : 2,
        "answer" : 4
    }]}
]
}
```

Comment: Well, have you tried anything? Which part is difficult for you? By the way, your example is not valid JSON. `[]` is an array, it should have no keys.

Comment: The `question` sibling of `testid` is using `[..]` like it's an _Array_, but has labels like it's an _Object_. That's not valid _JSON_, it's not even a valid _JavaScript_ literal.

Comment: Edited now.. and ive tried using the jquery serializeArray, and also looked at https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object , but i didnt seem to get that result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var form = $('#SomeForm').serializeArray();
var formObject = {};
$.each(form ,
    function(i, v) {
        formObject[v.name] = v.value;
    });
```

for more information :-

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/serialize-form-to-json/

Comment: You forgot to close quote

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var frm = $("#SomeForm");
var data = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());
console.log(data);

$("#test").click(function(){
    var frm = $("#SomeForm");
    var data = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());
    alert(data);
});
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/as55D/